# Debate about whether to use any tables in scientific articles

Tags: publications, science, tables

I have a new boss, who is experienced and has published a number of scientific articles. He is telling me that I should not have any tables in my articles, but rather make graphs for everything.  I agree that graphs are better, but I also think it's ok to add some tables for the less important variables. I tried to google it, but couldn't find that anyone else has raised the question before. It seems that using tables is so normal that nobody is questioning it (apart from my boss, apparently). I'd love to know how other people see this!

Comment: What field? ...

Comment: Typically you can have a graph if there is a single parameter of interest that varies wrt 1 or 2 input parameters. But if there are multiple result parameters for every input parameter, then you would probably need a table for easier comparison, esp if the result parameters contain data of different types - (time in seconds, memory in MB, method used, etc), etc for each input parameter.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- horticulture research

Comment: @NebUzer I guess his point is that you must be able to turn the results into a good graph, otherwise you are not looking at it in a simple and understandable way.

Comment: you can also put the graphs in an appendix in case someone wants all the data in an easy to copy form, and then put whatever is easiest to understand/demonstrate in the paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the wrong question whether tables are good or bad. The right question to ask is this: *How do I present the data in a way that makes the point I want to make clearest?*

There are many cases where figures are the best way to show a trend, in particular if the numerical data is of low accuracy. If you can only measure things to at best two digits of accuracy, and if the data changes significantly from one time point to another, then a table does not have a lot of information -- a figure (from which you can read about two digits of accuracy) will show the trend much better.

On the other hand, if you want to illustrate that your device can measure the same variable repeatedly to five digits of accuracy, then a graph is pointless: You can't see five digits of accuracy visually, and you need to show the data as a table to allow your readers to compare the repeated measurements.

In other words, whether a table or a graph is more appropriate is not a question that can be universally answered. It depends on what the *message* of your paper is, what it is *you want to show*, and how you *convey the message best* so it is easy for your readers to understand.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be a better way of looking at it and probably reflects my feelings better too. The main reason I asked the question is so I can be better equipped for an argument with my boss :)

Comment: @Meerkat Then you now have the arguments for that conversation spelled out for you!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you should include tables when the actual numerical values matter. That is, a graph is great for showing trends in the data, but it is difficult to read the actual numbers from a plot. But if your numerical results matter (say it's the kind of results someone else is likely to directly use in their work) then put them in a table.

Depending on the journal you could get away with just putting the tables in an Appendix at the end to not break up the flow of the text.

Answer (score -1):

There is a tendency among many older academics to avoid the use of tables. The reason for the dislike has more to do with the fact that tables were traditionally difficult to typeset well, rather than a specific preference for graphical displays. For example, historically, the American Psychological Association discouraged the use of extensive tables in their journals, and some APA journals set a specific limit on the number of tables that could appear in an article.

The decision to use tables or graphs should now be driven by your own goals in presenting the material. Keep in mind that you are likely to have the option of publishing on-line supplementary material along with your accepted article, so you can always present explanatory figures in the main text, but also upload files that contain tables of the data on which the figures are based.